# Store value type as a database column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb, laravel-5.8

What I need is, I think, quite common. I want to create a `global_variables` table to store some variables I need throughout my web app using MySQL. The problem is that every variable has one of multiple types (int, float, string, BLOB, etc.). So I need to be able to create my table with columns like `id`, `program_name`, `value_type`, `value` where `value` is going to be a string that I'll convert accordingly on getting/setting the value. So some sample records would be:

```
[
    ['program_name' => 'invoice_number', 'value_type' => 'int', 'value' => '12345'],
    ['program_name' => 'last_merge', 'value_type' => 'date', 'value' => '10.06.2020'],//etc.
]
```

What stops me is the lack of a column type `Type` in MySQL. Any help with any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

P.S. I'm using MySQL MariaDB with Laravel 5.8.

Comment: varchar as foreign key to a types table.

Answer (score 1):

Just store them as strings.

In a date context, the string will automatically convert.

In a numeric context, the string will automatically convert.

In a boolean context, the number 0 is false, anything else is true.

If you have counter-examples, let's see them.  There may be a simple workaround.

Comment: "anything else is true" - Not `'true'` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own constraint :

```
CREATE TABLE global_variables (  
     id serial,  
     ...
     value_type varchar(32),
     constraint check (value_type in ("int", "date", "varchar", "boolean" ... ))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some debugging and trials, I came up with a best working solution for my case. I registered the `value_type` column as an enum of the given allowed types and then created an accessor and a mutator (Laravel features) for my `GlobalVariable` model on the field `value`, which convert the values accordingly. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Nice.. You've found the worst possible solution ;-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Why would that be? I'd be happy to improve possible errors in that approach, care to elaborate?

Comment: Ok - maybe not the worst. But you should be carefull with ENUM. Some gotchas: Permits an empty string. Sorts in defenition order - not alphabetically. Changes can be quite costly on big tables.